# Basis of numeric comparison of VARCHARs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, varchar, comparison-operators

I know that when comparing two `VARCHAR` values in `MySQL` that I can use something like:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM . . .
WHERE VARCHAR_COL1 = VARCHAR_COL2
```

Or even:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM . . .
WHERE VARCHAR_COL1 > VARCHAR_COL2
```

In this case, the values of `VARCHAR_COL1` and  `VARCHAR_COL2` are made up of non-numeric characters.

I know that a numeric representation of the `VARCHAR` values will be for the comparisons but can anyone tell me what that is?

Comment: In the simplest sense, it uses the alphabetic sequence.  Formally, it uses the collation defined on the string/column/database/server:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-general.html.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. If you want to post your response as an answer, then I will accept it.